# How to Iterate an unknown object with unknown depth and unknown key/values in a component html in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, object, iteration

I Use Angular 6.0.0 and cannot update it due to some reasons. I get some jsons from API calls which are completely unknown either depth or key/values and I need to show them in my page as follow:

```
key a: value a
key b: value b
   key b1: value b1
   key b2: value b2
key c: value c
.
.
.
```

How do you suggest to do this?
Should I do this in my component or in HTML template?

Comment: You have nesting scenario and you can achieve this by using `ng-template` which pass and call itself.

Comment: So what is your question, how to iterate an object? If so look up recursion. Are you looking for suggestions how to output those? or finally are you looking to find out what to use, component or HTML template?

Comment: thank you all, @sloth I think yours is my answer